# Mono, WebClient & invalid SSL Certificates

Tags: c#, ssl, mono

I'm trying to port an existing Application to Mono 2.6.7/Linux.
One Task is to receive data via the WebClient method from Servers with an **invalid** SSL Cert.

Our .Net 3.5 Code under Windows to accept all certificates works fine:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = TrustCertificate;
StreamReader webReader = new StreamReader(webClient.OpenRead(url));
...
private static bool TrustCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate x509Certificate, X509Chain x509Chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
   // all Certificates are accepted
   return true;
}
```

I tried misc. things to achieve the same in Mono **without** using specific Mono dll's but always the same error:

> Error getting response stream (Write:
>   The authentication or decryption has
>   failed.): SendFailure

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The main reason is that Mono, unlike Microsoft's .NET implementation, does not include trusted root certificates, so all certificate validation will fail by default.

This page does an excellent job explaining how certificate validation on Mono works. It also describes how to implement your own policy responsibly, including sample code.

http://www.mono-project.com/UsingTrustedRootsRespectfully

The site is somewhat old and provides code for .NET 2.0, using the `ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy` property. You should use the newer, non-deprecated `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` property instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this instead (the callback property was implemented only recently I think):

```
ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new NoCheckCertificatePolicy ();
```

where `NoCertificatePolicy` is:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
 class NoCheckCertificatePolicy : ICertificatePolicy
 {
  public bool CheckValidationResult (ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request, int certificateProblem)
  {
   return true;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Note of caution: Please do NOT put this code into production. This is akin to introducing the same severe security vulnerability that was recently found in iOS and MacOS: http://www.neowin.net/news/serious-vulnerability-found-in-ssltls-on-os-x-mavericks-and-ios-7-easily-exploitable

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I validated certificates like said before, but also be sure, not to use **https** but only use **http** requests. For me it didn't work until I did both.